# Silverlight: Creating a round button template

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I decided to try making a circular button, so using expression blend, I dropped a button control on my xaml.  I then created a template from it by choosing "Edit Control Parts (Template)" -> "Edit a Copy".   I am trying to design it so that the left and right sides of the button were always perfect semi circles, so that no matter how tall or wide the button grew, the corner radius would max out at either half the width or half the length of the button, depending on which was smaller.  That way, if the button was stretched tall, the top and buttom would be perfect half circles, and if the button was stretched wide, the left and right would be perfect half circles.   Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is close, but making it a perfectly round edge is harder.  I've made it by making the round shape, not a rectangle with rouneded curves.  See if this helps:

```
    <Style x:Key="roundButton"
       TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.479*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.521*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.147*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.685*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.168*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
              <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
          </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Path Margin="-2,8,2,8"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Stretch="Fill"
                Stroke="#FF000000"
                Data="M25.999998,0.5 L26.499998,0.55732149 L26.499998,0.50000316 L184.5,0.50000316 L184.5,0.55732256 L185,0.5 C199.0833,0.50000429 210.5,13.483747 210.5,29.500002 C210.5,45.516144 199.0833,58.500004 185,58.500004 L184.5,58.44268 L184.5,58.500004 L26.499998,58.500004 L26.499998,58.44268 L25.999998,58.500004 C11.916747,58.500004 0.5,45.516209 0.5,29.500002 C0.5,13.483672 11.916748,0.50000429 25.999998,0.5 z"
                StrokeThickness="0" />
          <ContentControl FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                          FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                          Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#FFFF0000" />
</Style>
```