# xaml how to create a circle button with bound color

Tags: c#, silverlight

How do I create a circle shape button but with the color affected by binding.

I have already something like this:

```
<Button  Command="{Binding ShowDetails}" Background="{Binding Color} />
```

and the color that will be received will be of this format, for example: Colors.LightGray

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should mind your language while commenting.

Comment: -1 for your language in commenting

Answer (score 3):

If you google for "circular button template silverlight" you will find lots of blog posts that describe this process. Including previous StackOverflow questions:

[Silverlight: Creating a round button template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378568/silverlight-creating-a-round-button-template)

The basic steps are

1. Create a new `ControlTemplate` for your buttons that renders a circle, using an `Ellipse` for example.
2. If you want your `Buttton.Background` to set the Fill color, then use a `TemplateBinding` for the `Ellipse.Fill` property.

For example:

```
 <Button Content="MyButton">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Colin if i have for example the property color in my viewmodel, how do i connect that property in this code so i can fill color with that binding?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the control template for the button like this

```
 <Button Content="MyButton">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: You have a few mistakes here, where is the binding for the ContentPresenter.Content? Also, a TemplateBinding for your Ellipse would be better

Comment: Also ... Silverlight does not support x:Type markup extension!

Answer (score 0):

With the color binding :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyColor">LightGray</Color>

        <Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Left="141" Canvas.Top="61">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
      <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" />
</Grid>
```

Enjoy ;)